# Android - MyCustomView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, OnTouchListener

Tags: android, surfaceview, runnable, ontouchlistener

In my code MyCustomView extends the `SurfaceView` to draw a bunch of `bitmaps`. I want them to move according to touches so MyCustomView also implements `OnTouchListener`. Everything works but I'm wondering whether it is correct to implement `OnTouchListener` directly on the view rather than on the activity that contains it.
Is there the possibility that the touch listener interferes with the drawing thread (jeopardizing the performance and/or creating concurrency problems)?

Thanks a lot,

G

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to override the SurfaceView's method `onTouchEvent` instead of feeding it an OnTouchListener. Listeners were made in Java to make classes more reusable and following good object orientation practice, but what you want to do is very narrow and does not require a listener. Your MyCustomView is dedicated. That is why I prefer you override it instead because it is not meant to do anything other if I understood it correctly.